# Logout from facebook in ios

Tags: ios, facebook

I use this build in facebook sdk login [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/) and everything work great. I log out from facebook using this method `[[FBSession activeSession] close];` but when I logout then leave my app and then run it again I'm automatically logged in. I cant use method `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];` becouse when I try to log in again I'm ask for permission to app every single time. How then I should log out from facebook to be logged out after turn off and turn on then app, and dont be asking for permission every time?

PS. I use facebook login from facebook sdk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502152/logout-functionality-using-facebook-sdk-in-ios check this here is also a link for logout feature

Comment: I am sure the login button or control you are using is reading from the disk. Go to Library Directory of your app on disk and in preferences folder, there will be a file called com.yourcompanyName.projectName.plist.. Facebook login button reads content from there (keep in nsuserdefaults) and which in turn write it on the disk in library/preferences/plist file..

Comment: Hey, Check for the file I have mentioned above, This keeps all the user defaults on disk, and the facebook keeps - access token, permissions, expire time, etc information in user defaults on some key. Just check when you do closeAndClearTokenInformation on your session then see the changes are reflect in the file or not, else try to remove the keys/values used in the files by facebook. This will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Facebook SDK only ask for permissions first time, when User allows app for permissions then SDK does not prompt again for same permission.

Comment: op don't want to use this method

Comment: I know thats wierd but when I use [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; I'm redirect everytime to facebook login site with information that I already allow permission to my app. I really dont want to redirect to this page everytime

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you don't really log out when using `close`.
Are you sure that `FBSession.activeSession` is set ?

Take a look at how you create your `FBSession`. Try to use something like :

```
FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
[FBSession setActiveSession:session];
```

---

EDIT :

The problem might simply be that you are not really automatically log in, but just that when using facebook your SDK use the last login token (you have kept it since you don't use `closeAndClearTokenInformation`), if this token is not expired the login work without asking the user.

Comment: I dont create my FBSession. I use out-of-box  facebook-sdk mechanism to login

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{   
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];  
}  
NSUserDefaults *defauls = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defauls setObject:@"" forKey:@"signInUserID"]; // if you have saved an user info from Facebook in defaults set null to it
```

Comment: Nope, this dont help.

Comment: This is the old way of doing it.

Comment: @RenoJones what is the new way of doing this? Any ideas?

Comment: @Miraaj - This should do it for latest SDK - [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]